# Pexpect shutting down a shell script

Tags: python, variables, pexpect

I have two defined functions, `foo` and `bar` which run `pexpect` that calls a script from the command line using `pexpect.spawn`. Next it just sends a control-c using pexpect's `sendcontrol` and `close` to tell the script it's running to shut down, and then terminate the object. After the program runs tho, the object is still running in memory and it looks like control-c and/or `child.close` never reached `foo()`

The script should **terminate** my spawned object, but instead my `if` logic in `bar(child)` does not seem to have any effect on the object created in `foo()`

Here's the code:

```
def foo():
   child = pexpect.spawn ('./script.sh')
   return child
def bar(child):
   if child.isalive():
      child.sendcontrol('c')
      child.close()
   if child.isalive():
      print 'Child did not exit gracefully.'
   else:
      print 'Child exited gracefully.'
a = foo()
bar(a)
```

The program always ends by printing "Child exited gracefully" and but leaves my `script.sh` running in the background

This code here works tho:

```
def bar(child):
   child.sendcontrol('c')
```

that interacts ok with the object created in `foo()` but for some reason my other code with the `if` logic runs the `if` correctly but doesn't do anything to my object

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was my indentation in my .PY file was off by a charachter